# Can't use an instance variable of non-generic class inheriting from a generic class with specified type

Tags: c#, .net

I created classes like these:

```
abstract class AClass1<T>
{
    // some code here
}

class Class2 : AClass1<int>
{
    // some code here
}

class Class3 : AClass1<float>
{
    // some code here
}

class Class4<T> : AClass1<T>
{
    // some code here
}
```

so far it works. But in another class I'd like to have:

```
...
AClass1<T> variable;
```

and depending on specific needs set that variable to either:

```
variable = new Class2();
```

or

```
variable = new Class3();
```

or sometimes:

```
variable = new Class4<T>();
```

this produces a compile error with no possible cast or anything else I tried. At the moment I just changed all inheriting classes to generic like:

```
class Class2<T> : AClass1<T>
{
    // some code here
}
```

but it doesn't feel right, because there are no generic methods or anything there.

The question is what is the right way to do it, why, and why I can't do it using my original way?

By the way this is .net 2.0 as I'm doing it inside Unity3D.

To be more clear:

I have some specific cases e.g. for int type that I want to handle specifically, but there are other I'd like to have a generic class for. So I created some subclasses that specifcally handle some types and I have also a generic subclass that I use when there is no specific implementation for a type. When I create a specific class for a type it should not be generic as it handles only one type.

Comment: If `variable` doesn't need any of the generic members defined on `AClass1<T>` then why is it declared as such. If it does then `class Class2<T> : AClass1<T>` would seem correct.

Comment: You are right, I didn't mention that sometimes the inheriting class is generic. I corrected the question.

Comment: I am not entirely clear on what you want to do but can't. Can you post the code you would want to work if only it would compile and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited the question again with explanation at the end - hope it's more clear now.

Comment: In a way you want to declare `variable` as `AClass1<> variable;`, i.e. without specifying what the type parameter is. However, that is not allowed. In the same way you cannot have `List<> variable`. You will have to create a non-generic base class, or interface. That type can only hold those members that are independent of the type variable. For example the class `List<>` can implement a non-generic interface `IList` which holds the property `int Count { get; }`. *Addition:* Of course, `object` is a non-generic base class of any class, so you can use that, but it has a limited set of members.

Comment: Thank You @JeroenMostert ! It works and it works great. Please post Your solution as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done, hopefully with appropriate qualifications for innocent future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is trying to help you by ensuring you don't perform assignments that aren't guaranteed to work. This isn't legal:

```
void foo<T>() {
  ...
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
    AClass1<T> variable = new Class2();
  }
  ...
}
```

And that's because `Class2` is only compatible with `AClass1<int>` -- if we don't know what `T` is, we can't in general say it's compatible with `AClass1<T>`. In the code above, it's a certainty that the conversion is possible, but the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to determine this code is safe -- in general, without the `if`, it wouldn't be. Casting doesn't work either, because there is no conversion from `Class2` to `AClass1<T>` for arbitrary `T`.

To make this work, you have to forego compile-time type checking and force a runtime conversion -- it's always legal to cast to and from `Object` at compile time:

```
    AClass1<T> variable = (AClass1<T>) (object) new Class2();
```

If you get it wrong, the code will fail at runtime with an `InvalidCastException`.

This approach is dubious because it raises the question of why you are using generics (a compile-time type feature) and then circumventing them in your actual code. Code like this has to be carefully reviewed to see if this is really the most appropriate solution. Possible alternatives are introducing a non-generic base class, using containment for the generic types, or simply not using generics (if you're really only using `float` and `int`, is a generic base class adding anything?)

Comment: Unfortunately in my real case it's many more types than `float` and `int` and I want to abstract the inner working of my code from the end-user so it works as a usual generic class, but there are some specific cases. Great answer, thank You!

Answer (score 1):

A `Class2` object is not assignable to an `AClass1<T>` variable, because `Class2` is not derived from `AClass1<T>`, but `AClass1<int>`. These are incompatible types and the compiler cannot cast between them. Hence the compile error.

Maybe you can introduce a non-generic base class for `AClass1<T>`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your answer, but I can't - please see edited question, sometimes my inheriting class is generic and I don't know the type I'm working on.